# why when i add a for loop my jframe turns black?

Tags: java, for-loop, jframe

I am trying to make a flashing light in my jframe by creating a list of the colors and then cycling through them with a for loop and then repainting. but when I add a for loop to my code the whole thing bugs out and I get a black screen and it frezzes. Why is this happening?

```
 public class bb {

    static Color colors[] = {Color.ORANGE, Color.GRAY};
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setSize(400, 525);

    JPanel panel = new JPanel() {

        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

            JButton smallerButton = new JButton("Flash");
            JButton largerButton = new JButton("Steady");

            JPanel southPanel = new JPanel(); 
            southPanel.add(smallerButton);
            southPanel.add(largerButton);
            frame.add(southPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g.fillRect(180, 110, 10, 30);
            g.drawRect(180, 140, 9, 30);
            g.fillRect(180, 170, 10, 30);
            g.drawRect(180, 200, 9, 30);
            g.fillRect(180, 230, 10, 30);
            g.drawRect(180, 260, 9, 30);
            g.fillRect(180, 290, 10, 30);
            g.drawRect(180, 310, 9, 30);
            g.fillRect(180, 340, 10, 30);

            int i = 0;
            g.setColor(colors[i]);

            for(i=0; i <= colors.length; i++){

                g.fillOval(160, 70, 50, 50);
                if (i ==colors.length){
                    i=0;
                }
                frame.repaint();
            }

            smallerButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
            {
              public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
              {

                  String action = e.getActionCommand();
                  if (action.equals("Flash")){  
                  }
              } 
            });
        }
    };

    frame.add(panel);
    frame.validate();
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you're locking a SWING rendering thread in your loop.

Comment: @Reimeus's suggestion is a good one and I suggest that you follow it, 1+ to him. In addition your code above has some other significant problems, especially that your `paintComponent(...)` is doing a lot of things that it shouldn't be doing including creating and adding components to the GUI.

Comment: The paintComponent method is for painting **only**. You don't have full control over whether or even if it will be called, and it can be called **multiple** times, meaning lots of buttons being added. Also, you want to avoid component creational code or **any** code that slows down program flow within a painting method since these methods partly determine the perceived responsiveness of your GUI, and so you will want the painting methods (`paint` and `paintComponent`) to be lean, mean and ***fast***.

Answer (score 2):

This statement resets your loop index to 0 causing it to loop indefinitely blocking the [EDT](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html)

```
if (i == colors.length) {
    i = 0;
}
```

since you exceed the last array index in the `for` statement.

Take a look at using a [Swing Timer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) to achieve this functionality.

Comment: but thats what i want it to do. i want it to loop through 0-1 in the list for ever do make the flashing of the object

Comment: You don't want an infinite loop in your `paintComponent` method blocking the EDT. Take a look at using a [Swing Timer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) to achieve this